# SFINAE for an non-member operator overload

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, sfinae

I have a non-member operator overload to which I need to apply an SFINAE to make it work properly. I struggled with the implementation and when looking online for references couldn't quite find anything similar to what I needed and I know I have spent the better part of a day trying to make it work but to no avail and would appreciate some help from the community. Basically for the first operand overload I need to SFINAE type  std::is_arithmetic and for the second need to SFINAE type

AND type  std::is_class. Or if you have any other suggestions on the code below all comments are appreciated. Thank you in advance for the help folks.

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix3D
{
public:
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // *** CONSTRUCTORS ***
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /// Default Constructor
    //
    Matrix3D(void);

    /// External initialization Constructor
    //
    Matrix3D(const T& p_11, const T& p_12, const T& p_13,
             const T& p_21, const T& p_22, const T& p_23,
             const T& p_31, const T& p_32, const T& p_33);
    
    ....
    
            /// Vector division by matrix eqv to [M]^-1 * {V}
    /// \param p_vector p_matrix
    /// SFINAE enable_if type V std::is_arithmetic
    //
    template <typename U, typename V>
    friend Vector3D<decltype(std::declval<U>() / std::declval<V>())> operator/ (const Vector3D<U>& p_vector, const Matrix3D<V>& p_matrix);

    /// Vector division by matrix eqv to [M]^-1 * {V}
    /// \param p_vector p_matrix
    /// SFINAE enable_if type P && type Q std::is_class
    //
    template <typename P, typename Q>
    friend Vector3D<decltype(std::declval<P>() / std::declval<Q>())> operator/ (const Vector3D<P>& p_vector, const Matrix3D<Q>& p_matrix);
    
....    
private:
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // *** PRIVATE METHODS ***
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // *** PRIVATE DATA MEMBERS ***
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /// Matrix m_elements
    //
    std::array<std::array<T, 3>, 3> m_elem;
}


/// Vector division by matrix eqv to [M]^-1 * {V}
/// \param p_vector p_matrix
/// SFINAE enable_if type V std::is_arithmetic
//
template <typename U, typename V>
Vector3D<decltype(std::declval<U>() / std::declval<V>())> operator/ (const Vector3D<U>& p_vector, const Matrix3D<V>& p_matrix)
{
    Matrix3D<V> matrixinv = p_matrix.Inverse();

    return static_cast<Vector3D<decltype(std::declval<U>() / std::declval<V>())>> (matrixinv * p_vector);
}


/// Vector division by matrix eqv to [M]^-1 * {V}
/// \param p_vector p_matrix
/// SFINAE enable_if type P && type Q std::is_class
//
template <typename P, typename Q>
Vector3D<decltype(std::declval<P>() / std::declval<Q>())> operator/ (const Vector3D<P>& p_vector, const Matrix3D<Q>& p_matrix)
{
    Matrix3D<Q> matrixinv = p_matrix.Inverse();
    Matrix3D<double> dmatrixinv(matrixinv.m_elem[0][0].Get(), matrixinv.m_elem[1][0].Get(), matrixinv.m_elem[2][0].Get(),
                                matrixinv.m_elem[0][1].Get(), matrixinv.m_elem[1][1].Get(), matrixinv.m_elem[2][1].Get(),
                                matrixinv.m_elem[0][2].Get(), matrixinv.m_elem[1][2].Get(), matrixinv.m_elem[2][2].Get());
    Vector3D<double> dvector(p_vector.GetX().Get(), p_vector.GetY().Get(), p_vector.GetZ().Get());

    Vector3D<double> dres = dmatrixinv * dvector;
    decltype(std::declval<U>() / std::declval<V>()) elem[3];
    return Vector3D<decltype(std::declval<U>() / std::declval<V>())>(elem[0].Set(dres.GetX()), elem[1].Set(dres.GetY()), elem[2].Set(dres.GetZ()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might add `std::enable_if_t<your_condition<U, V>::value, int> = 0` as template parameter:

```
/// Vector division by matrix eqv to [M]^-1 * {V}
/// \param p_vector p_matrix
/// SFINAE enable_if type V std::is_arithmetic
//
template <typename U,
          typename V,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<V>::value, int>/* = 0*/>
friend Vector3D<decltype(std::declval<U>() / std::declval<V>())>
operator/ (const Vector3D<U>& p_vector, const Matrix3D<V>& p_matrix);

/// Vector division by matrix eqv to [M]^-1 * {V}
/// \param p_vector p_matrix
/// SFINAE enable_if type P && type Q std::is_class
//
template <typename P,
          typename Q,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_class<P>::value && std::is_class<Q>::value, int> /* = 0*/>
friend Vector3D<decltype(std::declval<P>() / std::declval<Q>())>
operator/ (const Vector3D<P>& p_vector, const Matrix3D<Q>& p_matrix);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33d0faa7cc4e279e)

or in C++20, you might use `requires`:

```
template <typename U, typename V>
friend Vector3D<decltype(std::declval<U>() / std::declval<V>())>
operator/ (const Vector3D<U>& p_vector, const Matrix3D<V>& p_matrix)
requires(std::is_arithmetic<V>::value);

template <typename P, typename Q>
friend Vector3D<decltype(std::declval<P>() / std::declval<Q>())>
operator/ (const Vector3D<P>& p_vector, const Matrix3D<Q>& p_matrix)
requires(std::is_class<P>::value && std::is_class<Q>::value);
```

Comment: Note that default template arguments are not allowed in friend function declarations. They need to be placed into their definitions.